# Containing a word in string and recording the following string

Tags: excel

I have about 1000 or so lines in orginal dataset. I need to use the isnumber(search(substring, string)) to find if my substring is in the column. IT reports TRUE or FALSE. I have up to three possible outcomes for if its TRUE, if its FALSE I will have 0 outcomes.

However, in stead of it reporting TRUE I would like to choose which of the Three outcomes I can record, and I would like to record the string.

I have tried using =isnumber(Search(substring, string))

```
=isnumber(search(substring, string))
```

My first column is

```
AAA-1-2
```

The column Im search for my strings will contain...

```
AAA-1-2-1
AAA-1-2-2
AAA-1-2-B
```

I would like to pick from these...I would only like to choose AAA-1-2-1.

Thank you.

So the result would look like...

First column

```
AAA-1-2
```

Second column

```
AAA-1-2-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP with a wild card:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1&"*",A:A,1,FALSE)
```

[image]

---

But based on your last deleted question I believe you really want:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C1,$A$1:$A$3))),COLUMN(A:A)))
```

[image]

To show that order does not matter:

[image]

Comment: I tried using this formula, I went to use it with =INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C1,$A$1:$A$3))),COLUMN(A:A))). It reported a #NUM!. Then I tried using =INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A:$A)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C1,$A:$A))),COLUMN(A:A))) with the $1 and $2 taken out from the A's. This worked for reporting the first AAA-1-2-1. I could not get AAA-1-2-2 or AAA-1-2-B reported by dragging the cell across to the other two cells. Is there a modification to make that work?

Comment: What was the formula in the second cell?

Comment: =INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A:$A)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C1,$A:$A))),COLUMN(A:A)))

Comment: If that is the formula in the second cell and the formula was done by dragging and `Column(A:A)` should have changed to `Column(B:B)`

Comment: I did a copy and paste so it's Column(A:A)

Comment: No in the second cell (E1 in my example), it should be `Column(B:B)` and in the third cell(F1 in my example) it should be `Column(C:C)`  As the formula is dragged over the formula will change automatically to the correct version.  Do not copy the formula to each cell.